# Does deadlock cause any active connection to be timed out/break?

Tags: sql, deadlock, connection-timeout

I have a basic SQL question, If there are two active connections, "A" and "B" to the SQL server, and let say a deadlock occurs between the two, so to avoid deadlock SQL server will roll back one of the transactions, either of connection "A" or of "B". Let say SQL server roll back the transaction of connection "A", does this roll back of transaction can cause a connection timeout/connection break for the connection A also? –

Answer (score 2):

Neither of those will occur. When a connection is choosen as a deadlock victim, all that happens is that the transaction will be automatically rolled back, and nothing else. The connection will still be alived (and can be used immediately again if desired), but any previous instructions on the killed transaction are lost and must be redone.

Timeouts are a completely different kind of events, and always controled client-side and happens when the client "gives up" in waiting for a response. But a deadlock is server-side generated and results in an error on the connection, but otherwise the connection is still alive, like many other errors.

Comment: Cool, let say the timeout value at the client side is set to 20sec, and the deadlock occurred is > 20 sec, so the connection will timeout then? right ?

Comment: In that case the connection will time out and the query cancelled. The deadlock will *not* occur, because the client will abort execution before the server decides to kill it. In a way timeouts and deadlocks "compete" for what kills the connection first, if the situation arise. The resulting effects are similar afterwards.

Comment: Thankyou, that answered my question!!